# IE7 run only inline scripts... and not seems to include src scripts

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, inline

my website is working in chrome, firefox and IE8. But when it comes to IE7 it doesnt work.
Only the inline scripts are working, and the included ones, are not.

what cause the problem? thank you!

Comment: Can you post your code, how do you include javascript files?

Comment: <script src="http : //www.domain.com/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Remove the spaces in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://www.domain.com/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                alert("It works");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

and it did work. A couple of reasons can be responsible for your problem:

- The spaces in your URL
- Some security options from your browser
- Some security options from your network (content blocker). Have you tried to load the javascript file directly (paste the URL into adressbar)?
- etc.

Comment: well, it works, as i said, the inline scripts are working. but the included once, doesnt.

Comment: Have you tried my example, because the jquery lib is loading from external source. If your browser have no access, the inline script won't work.